# What up with the openID/loging in?

Tags: support, openid, login

I have setup an account with openID, have logged in answered questions, etc.  When I am using my mobile broadband card I cannot sign in through openID.

Does this mean I just quit using chiphacker?  What can I do to get around this?  There is no open wifi around me.  When I am not using mobile broad band, I can log into openID and chiphacker just fine.

It's ticking me the F off!!

Comment: I just want to be able to participate... my openID account had enough reputation to participate in the site.  Should I create a new account not using openID?!  Is there a way to manually log into my openID?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I'll open a question in chiphacker and it says I'm not logged in...but then I reload the page and it's fine. Dunno if that's related or not.

Try another browser? Maybe it's a problem with Chrome? Never seen that before: "`Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): Unkown error.`"

Comment: It could be.  I'm running Google Chrome 3.0.195.38, and have no problems but I'm not using Google.  However, if I do try to log in to Google's services (mostly GMail) I've noticed that sometimes it tells me that cookies have to be turned on to use GMail.  Going back to Google.com and logging in again usually fixes it, but sometimes it takes several logins to not only clear the "cookie" error but get a successful authentication.  It may be, as odd as it seems, a Google/Chrome issue.

Comment: Try with a different browser and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you use a different browser profile when connecting via mobile broadband card?

That might prevent you from using your OpenID.

Answer (score 0):

Which OpenID provider are you using?  Can you log into the provider's site? Sounds like it's an issue you take up with them.

Comment: I am using Google.  I also can not edit this post or add an answer... was going to post screenshots.

Comment: here is a link to the screenshots.... I only seem to be having this problem with chiphacker  http://picasaweb.google.com/morgellon/RandomSights04#5418183980587392834

Answer (score 0):

Its possible your provider may be blocking through-requests. Can you try another OpenID enabled site to log into so we can try and isolate if the problem is with open-id requests or chiphacker?